# Can my Spotify app running on a computer communicate with an iPhone/android app?

Tags: iphone, spotify

It's pretty self explanatory. I basically want to send a message from an app i wrote for the iphone/android to a Spotify app that's running on a computer. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Only as you would communicate through a Javascript app running in a normal browser — i.e., through a common backend system.